# Angular 2 get all directives of the same type inside the directive class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I'm trying to achieve an active state on one of my directives, so that the element that has the directive on it gets an `active` class whenever `isActive` is set to `true` in the directive instance.

The issue is that I can't seem to pick up more than 1 directive at any given time, which also appears to be the same element which is fetching the other directives.

```
export class ModalOpenDirective {
  @ContentChildren(ModalOpenDirective) modalOpenDirectives: QueryList<ModalOpenDirective>;
  @Input() modalId: string;
  @Input() modalTemplate: string;

  public modalOpen: string;

  constructor(private modalApi: ModalApiService) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  open(): void {

    this.modalApi.open(this.modalId, this.modalTemplate);

    this.toggleActiveClass();
  }

  @HostBinding('class.active')
  isActive: boolean;

  toggleActiveClass(): void {

    this.modalOpenDirectives.map((directive) => {
      directive.isActive = false;
    });

    console.log(this.modalOpenDirectives);

    this.isActive = true;
  }
}
```

How can I make sure that it picks up all other directives of the same type? I'm pretty sure `@ContentChildren` is the way to go but it doesn't appear to work.

**EDIT:** Here's how I use them:

```
<button modalOpen modalId="test1">Open modal nr 1</button>
<button modalOpen modalId="test2">Open modal nr 2</button>   
<button modalOpen modalId="test3">Open modal nr 3</button>
```

So when `modalOpen` with `modalId="test1"` gets triggered, that button should get an `active` class and all other buttons should lose theirs.

Comment: `ContentChildren` is fine. Can you please show where the directives are applied and how they are passed to `ModalOpenDirective`?

Comment: I think you need to identify which element has been clicked. `ContenChildren with QueryList` will give you all instances of the directive. you needed to filter it out to get the right instance. But I guess plunkr is needed to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: @micronyks It only picks up itself, so that's not a problem at this moment. But I guess Gunter made a point. I'll have to create a wrapper directive I think.

Comment: Gunter is right. but I'm just figuring out how to send `modalId` with Guanter's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`modalOpen` only contains a single element, therefore `ContentChildren` only returns one.

If you change it to

```
<div modalOpen>
  <button modalId="test1">Open modal nr 1</button>
  <button modalId="test2">Open modal nr 2</button>   
  <button modalId="test3">Open modal nr 3</button>
</div>
```

`ContentChildren` will return 3 elements.

This won't pass `modalId` to `modalOpen` though.